# Pandas Dataframe Appending Extra Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas.DataFrame that have the following columns: `['agent', 'agentid', 'agentname', 'agentaddress']`.

When I concat this data frame with another data frame of same cardinality, it appends an extra column at the end with same name.

```
>>> print(df1)
   agent  agentid agentname agentaddress
0      1     1001      test        delhi
>>> print(df2)
   agent  agentid agentname agentaddress
0      2     1002     test1     vadodara
```

When I concat these two data frames, it gives me the following result:

```
>>> print(pd.concat([df1, df2], sort=False))
   agent  agentid agentname agentaddress   agentid
0      1   1001.0      test        delhi       NaN
0      2      NaN     test1     vadodara    1002.0
```

Comment: Check columns names, I guess some trailing whitespaces for `agentid` column in `df1` or `df2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check the dtypes of entire colums in both dataframes. Sometimes ids can be of categorical dtype

Answer (score 1):

I created separate csv files and tried out what you have done here : It worked perfectly fine, check the names of the columns if they are right in both the files.

Answer (score 0):

The column names 'agentid' is different in df1 and df2, so you get this result. Please recheck the column names 'agentid', ensure they are the same character string.